# curve fitting result error using matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, curve-fitting

I used Curve fitting plugin in Matlab to get a proper relation between in-calibrated temperature and calibrated temperature , it gave me this relation with that curve:

```
Linear model Poly6:
     f(x) = p1*x^6 + p2*x^5 + p3*x^4 + p4*x^3 + p5*x^2 + p6*x + p7
       where x is normalized by mean 100.7 and std 0.9139
Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       p1 =    -0.08382  (-0.4273, 0.2597)
       p2 =    -0.06449  (-0.4851, 0.3562)
       p3 =      0.3342  (-0.8434, 1.512)
       p4 =     0.09103  (-0.9764, 1.158)
       p5 =     -0.3258  (-1.459, 0.8071)
       p6 =       1.629  (0.9808, 2.278)
       p7 =       38.76  (38.49, 39.03)

Goodness of fit:
  SSE: 9.913
  R-square: 0.9322
  Adjusted R-square: 0.9239
  RMSE: 0.4498
```

and this is the used matrix for each one :

```
temp=[36 36.1 36.2 36.3 36.4 36.5 36.6 36.7 36.8 36.9 37 37.1 37.2 37.3 37.4 37.5 37.6 37.7 37.8 37.9 38 38.1 38.2 38.3 38.4 38.5 38.6 38.7 38.8 38.9 39 39.1 39.2 39.3 39.4 39.5 39.6 39.7 39.8 39.9 40 40.1 40.2 40.3 40.4 40.5 40.6 40.7 40.8 40.9 41 41.1 41.2 41.3 41.4 41.5] ;
uncalibrated_temp=[99.132 99.185 99.052 99.162 99.203 99.142 99.650 99.720 99.610 99.561 99.764 99.961 99.942 99.863 99.825 99.941 100.127 100.156 100.462 100.323 100.381 100.392 100.527 100.582 100.549 100.362 100.488 100.656 100.792 100.953 100.891 101.095 101.161 101.182 101.161 101.224 101.537 101.491 101.392 101.539 101.565 101.749 101.704 101.764 101.707 101.910 101.968 101.805 101.807 101.791 101.771 102  101.892 101.731 101  101.581 ];
[][1]
```

it gave me that graph :

but when I use that general equation it gave me this curve which is a lot different from the interpolated curve.
this is the code I wrote:

```
f_temp=uncalibrated_temp;
temp1 = -0.08382  *f_temp.^6  - 0.06449  *f_temp.^5 + 0.3342  *f_temp.^4 + 0.09103  *f_temp.^3 - 0.3258  *f_temp.^2 + 1.629  *f_temp + 38.76  
figure,plot (uncalibrated_temp,temp1)
```

it give the curve on the right , where the curve on the left is the one generated from the true points from the two matrices

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the Toolbox... but from a pure numerical point of view, putting values of magnitude 100 into a polynomial of degree 6 will be devastasting :)

Matlab avoids this problem by shifting and rescaling the values before doing the fitting process. The message

```
where x is normalized by mean 100.7 and std 0.9139
```

looks like the x-values have been shifted by 100.7 and scaled by 0.9139. So, if you write something like

```
f_temp=(uncalibrated_temp-100.7)/0.9139;
temp1 = -0.08382  *f_temp.^6  - 0.06449  *f_temp.^5 + 0.3342  *f_temp.^4 + 0.09103  *f_temp.^3 - 0.3258  *f_temp.^2 + 1.629  *f_temp + 38.76
```

in order to transform your x-values it should do it. Note again, that I do not own the toolbox and do not know the order of transformation steps. It might also be

```
f_temp=(uncalibrated_temp-100.7)*0.9139;
```

but I'm sure one of it is the right one. Please let me know, if you found a solution.

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an important line in the fit result

> where x is normalized by mean 100.7 and std 0.9139

try this

```
f_temp=(uncalibrated_temp-100.7)./0.9139;
```

Normalized in this context means bringing the values to 0 mean and 1 standard deviation. The values given by the model are the mean and standard deviation of your data. E.g. try

```
mean(uncalibrated_temp)
```

and

```
std(uncalibrated_temp)
```

You will see the values that the model gave you (100.7.. and 0.91..). To bring your data to 0 mean and 1 standard deviation, you subtract the mean from the data and divide it by the standard deviation. e.g.

```
f_temp=(uncalibrated_temp-mean(uncalibrated_temp))./std(uncalibrated_temp);
```